# Passing parameter to link_to rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, post

I wrote the following form:

```
<% remote_form_for :login,
      :url => {:controller => :usuarios, :action => :login },
      :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
          <p class="login_field">
            Login:<br />
            <%= f.text_field  'login' %>
          </p>
           <p class="login_field">
               Clave:<br />
              <%= f.password_field  'clave' %>
           </p>
           <br />
           <p align ="right">
               <%= f.submit 'Ingresar' %>
            </p>
             <p class="forgot">
               <%= link_to "Olvid&oacute su clave?", { :controller => 'usuarios', :action => 'olvido_contrasena', :login =>  }, :post => true %>
            </p>
            <br />
            <p id="error_msg_login"></p>
 <% end  %>
```

Now, In my controller I have:

```
def olvido_contrasena
    if request.post?      
      u= Usuario.find_by_login(params[:login][:login])
      puts u.email
      if u and u.enviar_nueva_clave
        flash[:message]  = "Una nueva clave ha sido enviada a su correo electronico."
        redirect_to :action=>'login'
      else
        flash[:warning]  = "No se pudo enviar la nueva clave."
        puts "fail"
        redirect_to "/admin_main"
      end
    end
  end
```

However, I have two problems:

1. The action is called as a GET (and it should be a POST).
2. The param[:login][:login] is not being sent....

What can I do here?

Thank you!

**I solved my problem by adding a new view with a new form after the user clicks the "forgot password" link.
EASIEST and CLEANEST solution.**

Comment: you are not clear with what you are asking in point 1. 
About point 2- inspect login input field, to check what's "name" field it has. that my be problematic.

Comment: the name of the input field is "login[login]" ...

Comment: Are you wanting the form to be submitted when you click on the link?

Comment: No, I just want to pass the "login" value of the input to the "olvido_contrasena" (which is a "forgot password" link)

Answer (score 1):

Basically -

You are clicking on link, which doesn't submit the form you have created, but "Submit" button can submit it.

As you are click a link, this is sending the GET request. If you want to send post request with form data, you may use, javascript event listeners to submit form on click of link.

As form is not being submitted, you are getting login[login] as nil.

To submit form with javascript you will be doing something like this with jquery -

```
$(".linkClass").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //This will stop get request.

    $("#formId").submit();
})
```

Comment: there's a way to get via javascript the value of the login input element and pass it to the "link_to" as a parameteR?

Answer (score 1):

In your example code, the login-value is actually empty:

```
<%= link_to "Olvid&oacute su clave?", { :controller => 'usuarios', :action => 'olvido_contrasena', :login =>  }, :post => true %>
```

Also - "post => true" is not how to make it into a POSTed form.

Usually you'd use button_to (instead of link_to) but as you are already inside a form (and forms don't nest), you can fake a post by passing as a *query string parameter* the attribute "_method" (yes, it starts with an underscroe). so your example would become:

```
<%= link_to "Olvid&oacute su clave?", { :controller => 'usuarios', :action => 'olvido_contrasena', :login =>  @usario.login, "_method" => 'post'} %>
```

Now the problem is that the person is not already logged in... so you can't get their "login" - and the login field above the link is not part of the link. So you'll probably need to add some funky javascript to update the link field-value when somebody types something into the field.

... but your controller action should *also* deal with the case when somebody has not yet typed anything in. For example, if params[:login] is blank. it should render a "forgot your password? well enter your login name here" kind of page.